# How can I query for specific dates in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase Realtime Database that stores objects as follows:

```
"userID" : { 
  "entry": "content", 
  "Date": "Thu Jan 02 2020 15:56:27 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)" 
}
```

I also have a time picker that allows me to pass my query function a date in the same format it is stored in, in Firebase.

I want to be able to grab all of the users entries for the date selected via my time picker.

My concern, outside of getting query to work, is that the timestamp in the date will make this difficult since the time the entry is created at will be different.

Comment: So you'd want the query to do a range query rather than fixed date.

Comment: Can you point me to some docs where examples are provided of this? Not seeing them on https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Comment: If you want your dates to be searchable, you shouldn't store them as strings.  It's customary to use a number instead that represents the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch.

Comment: @DougStevenson ohh, that's helpful. I think because of how Firebase restricts "queries" I'll need to return all of them, and convert them into string based dates client side.

Comment: It's totally fine to store two separate values: one to display, and another one to query. For example, if you want to query on day granularity, I'd store a property `"day": "20200102"`. That's the sortable/range-filterable version of the display string you have. Only once you start looking for more granular filtering (seconds and such) will I typically switch to storing timestamp values as numeric values. But even then, it's fine to also store a separate display string for the same moment.

Comment: Display purposes storing doesn't make sense to be honest. What about future i18n? That will cause a lot of trouble. I would say yes absolutely store them as timestamps not strings, and then in the application read the timestamp and convert it to the display to user based on local. The reason for this is even timezone, what if the server saves UTC and the user is in UTC+8 ? The user will end up seeing the wrong value.